# Is iOS NSNotification equivalent to Events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is iOS `NSNotification` equivalent to `Events` in other systems? Contrary to sending message is it really non blocking the sender process ?

Comment: Yes, but the difference is you have a single instance of NSNotificationCenter, which broadcasts a NSNotification that can be caught application wide, unlike .net for example, where you declare a public event in your class and can subscribe for it only if you have an instance of this class. And yes it's not blocking the sender process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNotification objects encapsulate information so that it can be broadcast to other objects by an NSNotificationCenter object.

Check out the following links.

[What is NSNotification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900352/what-is-nsnotification)

[NSNotification in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456246/nsnotification-in-iphone-sdk)