# How to pass textfield values from one view to another view

Tags: iphone

would  you tell  me,,      what  steps  i  have  to  add  in  applications  to  move values from a view  to  another  when   press  a button

Answer (score 0):

You can use The NSNotificationCenter which implements the Observer pattern.  You have one view that listens for an event and the other view notifies any listeners when the event is triggered, in your case the button pressed.

This SO response has good information on it.

[What is NSNotification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900352/what-is-nsnotification)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to notifications and delegates, you can always do the quick and dirty method of passing a self class reference forward from one view to the next, and use the previous view class reference in your current view.  Please see my blog post about this:

http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2009/10/04/passing-values-and-messages-between-views-on-iphone/