# Tabbar with same navigation controllers

Tags: iphone, sdk, controller, navigation, tabbar

I have implemented an navigation based view controller with several views and a model.

Now I add my navigation controller to the Tabbar via interface builder. (just dragged the whole bunch into it). It worked, I have got a new tab with all my views in it.

But now I want to add exactly the same navigation view controller again to another tab. I can also do this, the problem is, when I e.g. delete an entry in my table view, the entry is still visible in the other tab.

So what I need a way to update my model when I switch the tabs.

**Update:**

I added the `addObserver` in my `RootViewController` containing the table view. I placed it in "view did load", the postNotification in my delete method. No compile Errors, but also the tables do not update each other.

I uploaded my project, perhaps you could have a look?:

> http://www.perry-paul.de/unternehmenf.zip

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is by using `NSNotifications`.

When you load your view controller containing the tableView, sign up your tableView for notifications using

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self.tableView selector:@selector(reloadData) name:@"ModelUpdated" object:nil];`

That way `[self.tableView reloadData]` will get called every time you post the "ModelUpdated" notification.  So when you delete a entry, send out the notification using

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ModelUpdated" nil];`

Finally, don't forget to remove the notification (usually in `viewDidUnload`):

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:"ModelUpdated" object:nil];`

More info on `NSNotifications` in this question: [What is NSNotification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900352/what-is-nsnotification)