# NSNotification in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios

I wants to know about **NSNotification** in Objective C ,can any one tell me about right Source

Comment: [From here you can start, Seriously!!](http://www.google.com/search?q=NSNotification) and specially [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1900352/593709)

Comment: the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

To send a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
```

To register a class to receive the notification (normally in the init method):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myCallback:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];

- (void)myCallback:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    ... do something
}
```

Then to remove the observer in your dealloc

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very diffuse question.

If you want to read about NSNotifications, head over to the [NSNotification Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  on developer.apple.com