# AppDelegate on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone development and can any one tell me what the exact thing behind Appdelegate and where should it important..?I currently using this to make my variables global..!(using @Syntesis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this SO question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652460/what-is-the-appdelegate-for-and-how-do-i-know-when-to-use-it)

Also see this explanation: [App Delegate explained](http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/application-delegate-for-the-first-iphone-application-explained.aspx)

And more here: [What is an App Delegate?](http://blog.sekiur.com/2010/06/what-is-an-appdelegate/)