# What is APPDELEGET file?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the AppDelegate for and how do I know when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652460/what-is-the-appdelegate-for-and-how-do-i-know-when-to-use-it)

When we create any new project in objective-c.we get two appdeleget file..so waht is the meaning of appdeleget..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35313006/3767017 may it help u out

Answer (score 1):

Here is a website that answers your question. http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/application-delegate-for-the-first-iphone-application-explained.aspx