# Navigation From UIViewController to Appdelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I am trying to navigate from UIViewController class (name is CartViewController)to Appdelegate (name is SimpleDemoAppDelegate) by clicking on Button.

**The method and code for IBAction on button is**

```
-(IBAction) Go
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UIViewController* presentingViewController = appDelegate.viewController;
}
```

I have also tried

```
-(IBAction) Go
{
    SimpleDemoAppDelegate *appdelegate=(SimpleDemoAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:appdelegate animated:YES];
}
```

and pushViewController too, But it shows warning.

**Incompatible pointer type sending 'SimpleDemoAppDelegate *' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'**

Can someone explain to me why I see this warning?

Comment: I think you can not navigate to `AppDelegate` class. Its called very first when app is launched and generally used to store global variables and functions.. just call those methods and variables from any class...

Comment: What do you mean by navigate to AppDelegate...? is [self.navigationController popToRootViewController]; the one you are exepecting?

Comment: I have also tried..SimpleDemoAppDelegate *obj=[[SimpleDemoAppDelegate alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES]

Comment: @anonymous Actually I am trying to integrate two different demo app.

Comment: AppDelegate class is not a view controller. You can navigate only to a view controller. see this link to know about appdelegate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652460/what-is-the-appdelegate-for-and-how-do-i-know-when-to-use-it

Comment: @anonymous  Actually I am new to iOS and trying to integrate two different demo app, i have added all the files of second app to first. Now i have button by clicking on which my compiler has to jump to second demo app where at start SimpleDemoAppdelegate is

Comment: @xingzhi.sg thanks i tried that one to but didnt work, Actually I am new to iOS and trying to integrate two different demo app, i have added all the files of second app to first. Now i have button by clicking on which my compiler has to jump to second demo app where at start SimpleDemoAppdelegate is

Comment: For this requirement, you probably should reconsider the way to switch between the two app mode. You can only have one AppDelegate - so you need to merge the two appDelegates into one. You can consider -setRootViewController (UIWindow) as a way to switch between app modes

Comment: @xingzhi.sg yes you understand me well. please suggest me some proper links where i can refer solution for the same. Thanks

Comment: @xingzhi.sg I will check it -setRootViewController (UIWindow)

Comment: @xingzhi.sg Thanks it works fine now.. Properly merging was needed so single appDelegate must be there.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to write viewcontroller property of appDelegate see this

```
SimpleDemoAppDelegate *appdelegate=(SimpleDemoAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:appdelegate.viewController animated:YES];
```