# Multitask Issue in SpriteKit Game

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, multitasking

I'm developing a game with Sprite Kit but I am having a multitasking issue. When I press the home button, during the game execution, my `SKScene.paused` becomes true, and I make the proper changes to the app in my `applicationDidEnterBackground` method at AppDelegate.m, such as saving stuff with NSUserDefaults. Anyway, if I opened my app again, it should resume from where it left off, but what happens is that my app terminates and starts again. This only happens in my iPhone (in the iOS Simulator it works fine). Since I am new at creating games with Sprite Kit and creating apps at all, I was hoping for some clue of what could the problem be...

PS: I think the problem is something about the app not being "suspended" correctly, because if I press the home button and immediately reopen the app, it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(self.scene == nil) return;

    [self.scene saveUserDefaults];    
    [self.scene pausar];
    self.scene.paused = true;
}
```

In MyScene.m, inside the `initWithSize` method:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.scene = self;
```

And in the AppDelegate.h file:  `@property (weak, nonatomic) MyScene * scene;`
Now, the `saveUserDefaults` method, which is inside the MyScene.m file:

```
-(void) saveUserDefaults
{
    [userDefaults setBool:true forKey:@"active"];
    [userDefaults setInteger:highScore forKey:@"highScore"];
    [userDefaults setBool:soundOn forKey:@"soundOn"];
    [userDefaults setBool:musicOn forKey:@"musicOn"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Well, without seeing more of your code, it is impossible to know what is causing your issue.

First, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652460/what-is-the-appdelegate-for-and-how-do-i-know-when-to-use-it). Similarly, you should read up on the [UIAppDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) class since it is something you must know very well when programming on a phone where frequent interruptions like phone calls, etc can happen while someone is using your app.

More than likely, you have a problem with how you are responding to one of the protocol methods in the delegate.

Comment: Well, I did not put my code because there is no code, since I just save my NSUserDefaults in the applicationDidEnterBackground method. Do you think the problem is because of this? Lack of code? And why does it happen only in my phone and not in the simulator?

Comment: Well in general how can you expect others to know why your app is crashing if you don't provide any details? Since your app is crashing upon launch, then you should tell us exactly what is in your app delegate for the methods that are called during app launch.