# What is the AppDelegate.swift file for?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to programming but as a part of my learning I am trying to create something very difficult so I can learn along the way (I learn better from hands on experience.) I am using Parse to build my project and I was looking at The AppDelegate.swift file and was just curious, what is it for? Is it to create something universally to your app so you don't have to create something over and over in the same view controller? I'm confused as to what its purpose it.

Comment: Read the docs for `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/653318/4475605